# TemplateNotFound: index.html with Google App Engine & Jinja2

Tags: python, google-app-engine, templates, jinja2

I'm trying to build my first GAE app with jinja2. After overcoming a dozen small errors, now I'm stuck with this:

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2\webapp2.py", line 1536, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2\webapp2.py", line 1530, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2\webapp2.py", line 1278, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2\webapp2.py", line 1102, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2\webapp2.py", line 572, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2\webapp2.py", line 570, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\CG\Documents\udacity\HiMon\main.py", line 31, in get
    template = jinja_environment.get_template('index.html')
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\jinja2\jinja2\environment.py", line 719, in get_template
    return self._load_template(name, self.make_globals(globals))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\jinja2\jinja2\environment.py", line 693, in _load_template
    template = self.loader.load(self, name, globals)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\jinja2\jinja2\loaders.py", line 115, in load
    source, filename, uptodate = self.get_source(environment, name)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\jinja2\jinja2\loaders.py", line 180, in get_source
    raise TemplateNotFound(template)
TemplateNotFound: index.html
```

Here my yaml file:

```
application: himother
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico

- url: .*
  script: main.app

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.1"
- name: jinja2
  version: "2.6"
```

Here my code:

```
import os
import webapp2

import jinja2

jinja_environment = jinja2.Environment(autoescape=True,
    loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates')))

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        template_values = {
            'name': 'Serendipo',
            'verb': 'extremely happy'
        }

        template = jinja_environment.get_template('index.html')
        self.response.out.write(template.render(template_values))

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage)],
                              debug=True)
```

Here my .html template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Look Ma, I'm using Jinja!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        Hi there - I'm {{ name }}, and I {{ verb }} programming!
    </body>
</html>
```

Despite the error message, I have a folder called "templates" and, within it, created the index.html file:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I also have installed jinja2.

Does anyone have any idea of the cause of this error now?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should probably be using the `jinja2` version that's included in `webapp2_extras`.

The example of getting this set up is here: http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/api/webapp2_extras/jinja2.html#webapp2_extras.jinja2.Jinja2

The key difference is that instead of setting up the `jinja2.Environment` yourself, you do...

```
from webapp2_extras import jinja2
jinja = jinja2.get_jinja2(app=self.app)
jinja.render_template("index.html")
```

You will also likely need to include `jinja2` in your `libraries` section of `app.yaml`:

```
libraries:                                                                      
- name: jinja2                                                                  
  version: "2.6"
```

Comment: Hi, @jgeewax, I included "- name: jinja2 version: 2.6" in my libraries section (actually, it was already there, I make a mistake when pasting it in this question). I'll study the jinja2 version issue reading the link you pointed.

Answer (score 3):

Man.. I was facing the same problem as you and just found the answer.

```
jinja_environment = jinja2.Environment(autoescape=True,
    loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates')))

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        template_values = {
            'name': 'Serendipo',
            'verb': 'extremely happy'
        }

        template = jinja_environment.get_template('index.html')
        self.response.out.write(template.render(template_values))
```

The "jinja_environment" part don't need the extra [, 'templates']. This you should place before your index.html file string like:

```
template = jinja_environment.get_template('templates/index.html')
```

At least this is how it worked for me (oh, and I wasn't using the autoescape=True part either, but I guess its optional).

Thinking again, maybe you could even leave the [, 'templates'] part, but you would need to put a "/" before the 'index.html', making '/index.html', but this is another guess.

Comment: the ``autoescape=True``  was just right for the udacitity course on web development introducing templates

Answer (score 2):

After using the webapp2_extras setup described in [1] and here, I still had this error. I tried logging.info(jinja2.default_config). This showed that the undocumented default directory for templates is app-yaml-dir/templates/ ('template_path': 'templates'). I have tried everything but that. You can reset it, or leave it as it is, once you know it.

```
jinja2.default_config['template_path'] = "html"
```

If you prefer to put templates in various directories, just set it to empty and use the full path when rendering `render_response('module/home.html', **context)`

```
jinja2.default_config['template_path'] = ""
```

1. http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/api/webapp2_extras/jinja2.html#webapp2_extras.jinja2.Jinja2

Answer (score 0):

`jinja_environment = jinja2.Environment(autoescape=True,
    loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates')))`

Actually the line in your code means that you direct your request to the templates folder but it seems like you have not stored your "index.html" in the templates folder so just remove the redirection or transfer your index file to templates folder.